# Android Recyclerview set field name inside new thread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java2

I want to execute a heavy request inside the onBindViewHolder method and set the result to item filed. That is what I am doing:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final RealmArticle obj = getItem(position);
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    holder.data = obj;
    holder.row_name.setText(obj.getTaskName());

    Maybe.fromCallable( ()->
            "Executed " +
                    realm.where(RealmArticle.class).findAll().where().equalTo("idTask", obj.getIdTask()).equalTo("completed", true).count() +
                    " from " +
                    realm.where(RealmArticle.class).findAll().where().equalTo("idTask", obj.getIdTask()).count())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(res->{
                        holder.row_count.setText(res);
                        this.notifyItemChanged(position);
                        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            },
                    throwable -> Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s, %s", "Can not get items count", throwable.getMessage())));
}
```

You can see that I am doing my heavy request inside a new thread and then I'm setting the result to a filed. But it doesn't work asynchronously. (But it works when I do this request just as it is inside the main thread) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Maybe.just()`, that emit a items it's gets as a param, that means that the heavy Realm request resolves and executes before the `Maybe` even starts, and the result is then used by Maybe to construct a Maybe that emits this item.
What you need to use is `Maybe.fromCallable()` with the heavy request as the callable method, this will resolve at subscription time and not immediately as you desire, and will operate at background thread as excepted.

Additional issue with `Maybe.just()` is that it can't get null as param (as RxJava2 don't allow nulls), `Maybe.fromCallable()` will consider null as `Maybe` completion (no value).

Also, why are you calling `dispose()` immediately()? this will dispose and unsubscribe immediately, meaning if you will use `fromCallable()`, and your `Maybe` will operate async,  you will never get an answer (as you tell the Maybe to dispose and stop listen to events right after you've just started it)

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. I corrected the code as you suggested, but the result is the same. I edited a question with corrections. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? does the code inside the from Callable not called? did you got some exception? throwing a suggestion maybe you got an exception as you access Realm object from a different thread then it was created (you created it at main thread and trying to access at io thread) but i'm not enough familiar with Realm...

Comment: I didn't see a Log - Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created. I think the problem is - I can not use the realm in another threads. For such cases I need to use realm.executeTransactionAsync. Thank you anyway

Comment: if that's the problem you can simply try to create it inside the fromCallable

Comment: Creating the Realm instance inside callable do not solve the problem. - error - Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created. There is a special way for executing a Realm requests inside another thread - realm.executeTransactionAsync.

Comment: The problem was that "obj" variable inside "MayBe" is a Realm object. And I can not use it inside a new thread. I created a new wariable idTask outside of "MayBe" and now it works fine. Thank you. Can you tell me, should I dispose this "MayBe" after execution?

Comment: Great, I can see you have an answer on where to unsubscribe at another thread, please consider to accept the answer if that was helpful, thanks!